# SQL Loader: writing batch file (windows) for processing multiple data file

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sql-loader

I want to process all the .CSV in files (data files) in specific folder. My problem is how can i pass this file name to sql loader as every time it would be different file name.

I want to have all this stuff in single batch file so that i can schedule it whenever i wish.

Can anyone help me out pls?

Thanks in advance....

Mehul

Answer (score 4):

Assuming for each .csv file there is a corresponding .ctl (control file) the following should work:

```
for %%i in (*.csv) do ( 
   sqlldr data=%%i control=%%~ni.ctl log=%%~ni.log
)
```

This assumes the files are in the current directory. You might want to add the approriate `cd` commands before iterating over the input files.